# ¿cómo relizar una búsqueda por el nombre del alumno en vez de su matrícula?

Tags: laravel

soy principiante en la programación. lo que ocurre es que tengo dudas para realizar una búsqueda por el nombre del alumno, ya que la búsqueda la realizo por su matricula. esto para consultar el historial de los pagos que ha realizado cada alumno. he aquí las relaciones y el código que uso para buscar por matricula.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

método del modelo matricula:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

método del modelo alumno:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

código en el controlador del modelo pago:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no pongas capturas de pantalla con el código y texto relevante. Copia y pega el texto en la pregunta para que también nosotros podamos copiarlo en nuestros entornos de desarrollo para intentar reproducir el problema. También te sugiero leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, y aprovechar y [hacer el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con querybuilder quedaria algo asi:

```
//Se va a usar la dependencia DB
use DB;


//Dentro de tu funcion
$usuarios = DB::table("alumnos")
            ->select("alumnos.nombre AS nombre",
                     "matriculas.matricula AS matricula",
                     "pagos.fecha_cobro AS fecha_cobro",
                     "pagos.descripcion AS descripcion")
            ->join("matriculas","alumnos.id","matriculas.alumno_id")
            ->join("pagos","matriculas.matricula","pagos.matricula")
            ->where("alumnos.name",$nombre)
            ->get();
```

Es la forma mas rapida de obtener la informacion o bien desde eloquent lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera

```
$alumnos = Alumnos::where("nombre","=",$nombre)->matriculas()->get();
```

La fuente del codigo en eloquent la puedes encontrar en [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Cierto, modifico mi respuesta

Comment: Talvez no fui tan claro. lo que pasa es que actualmente desde la vista recibo la matricula del alumno y realizo la búsqueda en la tabla matricula y muestro los datos del alumno y los pagos que ha realizado, esto mediante las relaciones con las tablas respectivas. Pero ahora quiero recibir de la vista el nombre del alumno y buscarlo mediante la tabla matricula ya que para que sea alumno debe estar matriculado y hacer la misma función de mostrar los datos. Gracias !

Comment: Ya entiendo, te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y eso lo puedes hacer de una manera muy facil, si guardaste toda la informacion en Auth puedes acceder a ella como `Auth::User()->nombre` si no lo estas guardando en auth puedes hacer la busqueda dentro de la vista, pero para ello si necesitaria ver de donde sacas puntualmente el datos en tu vista.